# is tan(π/2 - x)=cot(x) because tan in the 2nd area is "negative" and also cot(-x) equals to -cot(x)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, angle

trying to figure out if that negative/positive calculation is true.
and so at the end there will be two negative and the cot(x) will be positive.
is that so?

thank you.

Comment: co-functions are named this way because of the "co-angles" that live in the same right triangle.  e.g. sine(90 degrees-x)=co-sine(x). draw the right triangle and look at "soh cah toa". the second in your title is because cotangent is an odd function. sine is odd, cosine is even. hence their ratio is odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosine, cosecant, and cotangent are so named because they are *cofunctions* of sine, secant, and tangent respectively. That means one function of angle $\theta$ (in radians) will be its cofunction of $\theta^c:=\pi/2-\theta$, the complement of $\theta$:

$$\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta^c)\\
\csc(\theta)=\sec(\theta^c)\\
\cot(\theta)=\tan(\theta^c)$$

The latter two identities can be derived from the first identity. In particular,

$$\cot(\theta)={\cos \theta\over\sin\theta}={\sin (\theta^c)\over\cos(\theta^c)}=\tan(\theta^c)$$

---

Also note sine is an *odd* function and cosine is an *even* function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions)):
$$\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta\\\cos(-\theta)=\cos\theta$$

In particular, it follows that cotangent is an odd function:
$$\cot(-\theta)={\cos(-\theta)\over \sin(-\theta)}={\cos(\theta)\over -\sin(\theta)}=-\cot \theta.$$